# Unexpectedly found nil - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I try to put in the localStorage text from the searchbar but I have a problem. I think it's :

```
var newMessages = Messages(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)


@IBAction func createMessage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Messages", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    var newMessage = Messages(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    newMessage.locate = self.searchBar.text
    context.save(nil)

    println(newMessage)

}
```

i have an error :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Obviously one of the variables that is force unwrapped with `!` is nil. Use the debugger to step through that method and inspect each variable.

Comment: yeap ! ent is nil, but why ! Thanks

Comment: Use the breakpoints in Xcode to check which variabile is nil.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved ! I worked in Messages.xcdatamodeld but not in myProjectName.xcdatamodeld
Thanks to all of you

Comment: I used Messages.xcdatamodeld and not myProjectName.xcdatamodeld

Comment: Did you mean you had to re-name it? And there was no problem after re-naming?